# positioning a circle center depending on image position

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <style type="text/css">
#field
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    .Ninjaimg
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        display:none;
        cursor:pointer;
     }
        .circlle
        {
         width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border:1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        display:none;
        }
</style>  
     <script type="text/javascript">  
        function makeNewPosition() {

            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var h = $("#field").height() - 30;
            var w = $("#field").width() - 30;

            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

            return [nh, nw];

        }

        $("#Start").click(function () {
            var newq1 = makeNewPosition();
            var newq2 = makeNewPosition();
            $("#ninjaimage1").css("display", "block");
            $("#ninjaimage1").animate({ top: newq1[0], left: newq1[1] });
            $("#ninjaimage2").css("display", "block");
            $("#ninjaimage2").animate({ top: newq2[0], left: newq2[1] });
            // $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        });
      </script>
     <div id="field" >
    <img src="ninja.png" id="ninjaimage1" class="Ninjaimg"  />
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="ninjaimage2" class="Ninjaimg" />
    <div id="cirlce1" class="circlle"></div>
    <div id="cirlce2" class="circlle"></div>
      </div>
       <input type="button" id="Start" value="startGame"  />
```

when i click on startgame the two image take random position inside the div my question is that when the two image take their position i want to position the two circle in a condition that their center are the images themselves

Comment: Do you want to move the circles after the images moved? or do you want to move the circles with the image in them?

Comment: if for image 1 when it stop moving i know it's coordinate the x and the y those x and y should be the center of the circle

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/vmP3s/

Comment: yes exactly what i want but why did you used -60 ?

Comment: the height of half the circle is `75px`. In that half there must be half of the `image` (in order for it be in the middle). Half of the image is `15px`. That means that from the half image to top there has to be `60px` distance.